# How to map fbmessnger recipient id to fbbid?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-messenger

Is there a way by which we can map between the messenger recipient id with Facebook id or Facebook fbbid. Currently there seems to be no way by which we are able to connect both of these ..

Comment: I think it's impossible. You can only retrieve basic information about a user, see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference#user_profile_request